# Question marked as off-topic

Tags: discussion, support

[This question](https://superuser.com/questions/1275712/calculating-an-appropriate-wattage-for-my-servers-new-psu?noredirect=1#comment1882715_1275712) marked as off topic because it's "seeking for hardware shopping recommendations".

The question title itself makes clear this is an incorrect reading (*"Calculating an appropriate wattage for my server's new PSU?"* - specifically asks about "calculating an appropriate wattage", not what model to buy).

It asks how one can appropriately calculate a suitable wattage that's appropriate for a file server build with a large number of HDDs. That's as much on topic as asking how many cores, how much RAM, what speed processor, or any other "how much is appropriate for these needs" question.

It even says up front, *"I don't need a brand recommendation"* and *"It's the size that needs to be sensible. What PSU size would be "safe" for this build?"*

## Similar questions:

**What size PSU do I need?**

- [How much power is enough?](https://superuser.com/questions/86144/how-much-power-is-enough)
- [How to determine what size backup power equipment is needed?](https://superuser.com/questions/704120/how-to-determine-what-size-backup-power-equipment-is-needed)
- [How much power supply does a typical PC build need?](https://superuser.com/questions/126306/how-much-power-supply-does-a-typical-pc-build-need)
- [How much voltage (and ampere) does the PWM input on 4 pin fan need?](https://superuser.com/questions/720644/how-much-voltage-and-ampere-does-the-pwm-input-on-4-pin-fan-need)
- [How can I evaluate how much power (from power supply) is needed based on PC configuration?](https://superuser.com/questions/348849/how-can-i-evaluate-how-much-power-from-power-supply-is-needed-based-on-pc-conf)
- [What size power supply would I need for a computer with these specifications?](https://superuser.com/questions/43866/what-size-power-supply-would-i-need-for-a-computer-with-these-specifications)

**What size RAM do I need?**

- [RAM and Windows 7, how much do I need?](https://superuser.com/questions/202726/ram-and-windows-7-how-much-do-i-need)
- [How much RAM can I put in an ASUS Q550LF?](https://superuser.com/questions/814133/how-much-ram-can-i-put-in-an-asus-q550lf)
- [How do I determine how much RAM I actually need?](https://superuser.com/questions/1019704/how-do-i-determine-how-much-ram-i-actually-need)
- [How much RAM do you need to run Windows 7 usably in a VMWare virtual machine?](https://superuser.com/questions/203446/how-much-ram-do-you-need-to-run-windows-7-usably-in-a-vmware-virtual-machine)

**What size storage do I need?**

- [ReadyBoost - How much space needed?](https://superuser.com/questions/180374/readyboost-how-much-space-needed)
- [How much storage I need for this CCTV system and what capacity it has?](https://superuser.com/questions/1254027/how-much-storage-i-need-for-this-cctv-system-and-what-capacity-it-has)
- [How much disk space do I need for running an Ubuntu Live CD?](https://superuser.com/questions/351861/how-much-disk-space-do-i-need-for-running-an-ubuntu-live-cd)

Can the question be reopened, please?

Comment: FWIW, your question is on-topic at [hardwarerecs.se], where you already have an account. Not just on-topic, in fact, but an excellent question.

Comment: I'd also add. Maybe you should mention the merits of your question, rather than throwing a giant list of questions in your request for reopening...

Comment: @ArtOfCode - But I'm not really after a product suggestion. I want to know, if I have 20 HDDs churning, do I need to allow 20 x absolute peak wattage, or does some kind of averaging take place that its unlikely they will all be exactly at peak at the same time, what safety margin is sensible,  or how  _large HDD array_ power needs are calculated. That's why I originally asked at electronics SE. (They moved it here, but it seems that was wrong?) I don't want any specific product suggestion, because that's something I'll consider in my own time and depends on a lot else irrelevant to the Q'

Comment: @Stilez Gotcha. This may actually be where you're having issues. Your question _as it currently stands_ asks for a product recommendation, and is on topic for HR. If you rephrase it a bit to make it more obvious that you're not asking for that, you may have more luck. Your comment was a good explanation, actually, so including that in the question may help.

Comment: Your question would receive a better answer at HRSE then tab SU

Comment: "Tab"? I don't know the term.

Comment: Ignore the word tab.  Obviously a typo

Answer (score 5):

If it were reopened I'd vote to close it as a duplicate of either:

[How can I evaluate how much power (from power supply) is needed based on PC configuration?](https://superuser.com/questions/348849/how-can-i-evaluate-how-much-power-from-power-supply-is-needed-based-on-pc-conf)

or

[What size power supply would I need for a computer with these specifications?](https://superuser.com/questions/43866/what-size-power-supply-would-i-need-for-a-computer-with-these-specifications)

Given that it will still end up closed there seems little point in reopening it just close it again.

Adding a comment pointing the user at these questions will achieve the same goal as closing as a duplicate in the at the user will be pointed at the question(s) they need to read.

Comment: Its not a duplicate. I read those, as well as the faq. None of them say how to evaluate power needs of a drive array. See comment to ArtOfCode abovr

Answer (score 3):

You should start by reading the help pages provided:

> [off topic](https://superuser.com/helpcenter/on-topic) - each community decides which specific topics are and
>   are not allowed on their site.
>
> This question does not appear to be about computer software or
>   computer hardware within the scope defined by the community. What's
>   on- and off-topic is not always intuitive, so it may be necessary to
>   reword the question to fit this site's scope after reviewing the
>   community guidelines.
>
> Consider editing the question or leaving comments for improvement if
>   you believe the question can be reworded to fit within the scope.

Source [What does it mean if a question is "closed" or "on hold"?](https://superuser.com/help/closed-questions)

Do you see what is says there?

"Consider editing the question or leaving comments for improvement if
you believe the question can be reworded to fit within the scope."

That means you should edit your off-topic question to bring it into scope. Editing will put it in the reopen queue where users can cast their votes to have it reopened (or not).